# C# Unit Test is not recognizing other classes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

1st - Help the community, if you give a negative mark, at least explain why, so I will not repeat it!

I am a Begginer, and I'm trying to test a simple class. But my UnitTest do not recognize the other namespace, even though I have added the Reference.
[See the reference above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRCfR.png)

I can not use the "using" directive:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcgsB.png)

It's a .net Core 3.1 project. VS 2019 community

It probably is something really silly, but I'm stuck in it,and have tried everything I know.

The class I want to import

```
namespace DI.BLL
{
    public class ContainerBuilder
    {
        private readonly IList<Type> _registration = new List<Type>();

        public void Register<T>()
        {
            this._registration.Add(typeof(T));
        }

        public Container Build() => new Container(_registration);
    }
}
```

The test code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Xunit;
using DI.BLL;

namespace DI.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Container
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Should_Be_Able_To_Resolve_A_Class_Instance()
        {

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.Register<Cars>();
            var sut = builder.Build();
            Assert.IsNotNull(instance);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: how did you create the reference? Did you reference the project or the compiled DLL?
Please check the namespace in your classes you are referencing.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, the namespace looks correct. You added the reference by choosing "Project" in the "add references" menu, right? Are you able to build the DI.BLL project alone?

Comment: Side note : you don't need any attribute on the test class. `[TestClass]` is not used by  xUnit.

Comment: Other question : what are exactly all the error messages when you build? Sometimes, there is another error somewhere that confuses the compiler, and it will complain about  not being able to find existing things. Sometimes, right-click on solution and "clean", then "rebuild" can un-block Visual Studio.

Comment: Thought [TestClass] was used for all unitTests. Thank's for letting me know. Yes I can build it alone.

Comment: is `Cars` a public class in the same namespace?

Comment: Are both your projects using compatible framework versions?

Comment: @GeoffJames, thank's friend. That was it! Working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Geoff James said, I was using different versios of the framework
The project class was using the Core framework, while the Test project was using the .NET 4.7. 
Got them into the same version and it's working perfectly